# The Spinner Can't Fill With Data From WebService

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, spinner

I am trying to get a data from the database from the asynctask method 
but this error happen to my code, with knowledge that the same code I used in other activity and everything is Ok. This is the Logcat

```
09-14 15:01:50.575: D/GestureDetector(16972): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
09-14 15:01:50.705: D/AbsListView(16972): Get MotionRecognitionManager
09-14 15:01:52.375: D/AndroidRuntime(16972): Shutting down VM
09-14 15:01:52.375: W/dalvikvm(16972): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f522a0)
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972):    at com.example.t.m.r.AddNewAttendActivity$GetClasses.onPostExecute(AddNewAttendActivity.java:218)
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972):    at com.example.t.m.r.AddNewAttendActivity$GetClasses.onPostExecute(AddNewAttendActivity.java:1)
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
09-14 15:01:52.380: E/AndroidRuntime(16972):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your AddNewAttendActivity.java class file or just line number 218

Comment: @Metalhead1247       `spin_class.setAdapter(adapter1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Have you initialized Spinner in onPostExecute?**

before line 218   spin_class.setAdapter(adapter1);

You have to Initialize it in the **onPostExecute**  because you are in AsycnTask which is not the main Thread!

Comment: I always initialize the spinners In the Create Method , Even in second activity in initialize it in the create Method and it work Fine ...
On the Other Hand Thanks for help me it works now after adding the initializing Code in the onPostExecute , Thanks Alot